# Android SDK Manager Extras

Tags: java, android

The Android SDK is shipped with tools:

- Android SDK Tools (v22.0.1)
- Android SDK Platform-tools (v17)
- Android SDK Build-tools (v17)

and extras:

- Android Support Repository (v1)
- Android Support Library (v13)
- Google AdMob Ads SDK (v11)
- Google Analytics App Tracing SDK (v3)
- Google Analytics SDK (v2)
- Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library (v3)
- Google Play Services (v7)
- Google Repository (v1)
- Google Play APK Expansion Library (v3)
- Google Play Billing Library (v4)
- Google Play Licensing Library (v2)
- Google USB Driver (v7)
- Google Web Driver (v2)
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) (v3)

Some of them are documented on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) and other websites. However, I didn't find anything related to the following:

- Android Support Repository (v1)
- Google Analytics App Tracing SDK (v3)
- Google Repository (v1)

What are they?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Android Support Repository and Google Repository are Maven repositories that provide access to the latest optional libraries from Google for use alongside the new [Gradle build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) used by [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html):

- com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0
- com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.0
- com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:13.0.0
- com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36

As per the [announcement post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/4Yhpn6p9icf).

Google Analytics App Tracking SDK is for [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)'s [Android SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/).

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but Google Analytics App Tracing SDK revision 3 is not the v3 but v2.0.4 (at least using the mac android sdk manager). You can check it with the Readme.txt available in SDK_PATH/extras/google/analytics_sdk_v2

If you want the latest version you have to download it on the website.

Regards,